# Asking for user input between 2 genders using a while loop and to be stored in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

Want to create a small program that can ask a user a question. Do you want your character to be Male or Female? And output the result. However as you can tell the results are poor from my side.

Can someone give me a hand in fixing this mess as I feel I have over complicated it.

Just some general rules that the program must have:

- It must accept both **"Male" and "male"** as input and vice versa for
  female
- The user input must be stored in the variable created.
- If the user types anything else that is not: 'female' 'Female' 'male' or 'Male' they must try the question again (which is why I put in a while loop)

It's strange but this should be simple for me normally but I've made a bit of a mess of it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
gender = None

gender = str(input("Enter your Gender1: "))
while gender != 'Male' or 'male' or 'female' or 'Female':
    gender = input("Enter your Gender2: ") 
if gender in ['Male', 'male']:
    print("You have chosen Male")
if gender in ['Female', 'female']:
    print("You have chosen Female")

print(gender)
```

I don't mind the whole method changing where options can be used such as:

- Press 1 for 'Male' or 2 for 'Female'

Would be of a help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python 3.8, you can do:

```py
def ask_gender() -> str:
  return str(input("Enter your Gender: ")).lower()

valid_genders = ["male", "female"]
gender = None

gender = ask_gender()
while gender not in valid_genders:
  print("Unknown gender, try again")
  gender = ask_gender()

print(f"You have chosen {gender}")
```

Comment: ah thank-you so much it worked:! Learning something new everyday :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing twice eg. gender != 'Male' or gender != 'male' use lower.

```py
while gender.lower() != 'male' ...
```

Comment: hi there , really appreciate the reply, what does the '.lower' function mean exactly?

Comment: it just makes all characters in string lower case, eg. "Female".lower() gives "female", "ExAmpLe".lower() gives "example".

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
while gender != 'Male' or gender != 'male' or gender != 'female' or gender != 'Female':
```

Because in your case,  `'male'` evaluates to `False`

Comment: Or `while gender.lower() not in {'male', 'female'}:`

Answer (score 0):

```
x=gender.lower()
if x="male":
    print "U re Male"
else if x="famale":
    print "U re Famale"
else:
    print "You enter Wrong gender"
```

Comment: hi, please consider adding some more information. Answers like this are low quality, since other people may have problems to understand those. Adding 2-3 sentences are always helpful.